# Deploying git clone into Windows 10 inetpub wwwroot

Tags: git, www, windows-10-pro

I have a brand new `Windows 10 Professional` installed, configuring for the first time. I have a local web presence that I like to deploy, typically from *Git repository* straight into whatever the hosting mechanism is. Literally, historically I would literally `git clone src/ dest/` and be done with it. Under *Windows 10*, apparently that is `/c/inetpub/wwwroot`, correct? Problem is, there are apparently security restrictions on `/c/inetpub/wwwroot/` and I am getting errors like, `fatal: could not create work tree dir 'cloned_dir'.: Permission denied`, and just generally `Permission denied` to do much of anything in that directory. Curious about why that is, interested in constructive alternatives to what I am  trying to accomplish here, goal: literally, just clone the directory in so that the web service "picks it up" seamlessly. One thought, for instance, maybe I clone into a completely separate directory, and create a symbolic link to that directory from within the `wwwroot` directory? Thoughts? Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I see... So, I added the `IIS` *Windows Features for Windows 10* and did just this, cloned into a separate folder that I do control, and added that *Virtual Directory* under `IIS Manager`.